# Editar Noticia y mantener misma imagen class.upload.php

Tags: php

Me gustaria saber como puedo resolver este inconviente.
Estoy usando la clase class.upload.php.

Al editar una noticia, quiero que si no selecciono una nueva foto en el input file, ME MANTENGA LA FOTO GUARDADA (o sea la primera que subio al cargar esa noticia).
Me sale correctamente el UPDATE cuando edito todos los campos includo la imagen de la noticia, pero lo que no me sale es cuando solo edito los input, sin agregar una nueva imagen.

Mi codigo es este:

```
elseif ($accion == 'modificar') {

    $idNoticia = $_POST['idNoticia'];
    $imagenNoticia_guardada = $_POST['imagenNoticia-guardada'];
    $tituloNoticia = $_POST['tituloNoticia'];
    $noticiaCorta = $_POST['noticiaCorta'];
    $noticiaCompleta = nl2br($_POST['noticiaCompleta']);
    $imagenNoticia = new upload($_FILES['imagenNoticia']);


    if (empty($imagenNoticia)) {
        $imagenNoticia = $imagenNoticia_guardada;
    }

    if ($imagenNoticia->uploaded) {
      $imagenNoticia->image_resize              = true;
      $imagenNoticia->image_ratio               = true;
      $imagenNoticia->image_x                   = 573; //ancho
      $imagenNoticia->image_ratio_y             = true; //alto de acuerdo al ancho, mantiene perspectiva.
      $imagenNoticia->image_watermark           = '../img/watermark.png';
      $imagenNoticia->image_watermark_position  = 'TL';

        $imagenNoticia->process('../img/noticias/');
        if ($imagenNoticia->processed) {

            $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE noticias SET tituloNoticia = :tituloNoticia, noticiaCorta = :noticiaCorta, noticiaCompleta = :noticiaCompleta, imagenNoticia = :imagenNoticia WHERE idNoticia = $idNoticia"
        );

            $statement->execute(array(
                ':tituloNoticia' => $tituloNoticia,
                ':noticiaCorta' => $noticiaCorta,
                ':noticiaCompleta' => $noticiaCompleta,
                ':imagenNoticia' => $imagenNoticia->file_dst_name
            ));

            echo "La noticia ha sido editada correctamente.";
    }
}
```

El problema a mi parecer es en esta linea que algo estoy haciendo mal, o lo estoy asignando mal.

```
    if (empty($imagenNoticia)) {
    $imagenNoticia = $imagenNoticia_guardada;
}
```

No me muestra NINGÚN MENSAJE DE NADA. Incluso agregue un echo dentro de ese if y tampoco lo muestra.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

a mi parecer según la lógica que tienes, deberías de tener dos consultas: 1.si hay imagen {update todo + imagen} 2. else { update todo menos imagen}, por que si envías un update a una campo de la tabla sin valor va a fallar la consulta, y si envías "update = ' ' " vació te va a borrar el nombre anterior.

```js
if (!empty($imagenNoticia)) {
  $imagenNoticia = $imagenNoticia_guardada;


  if ($imagenNoticia - > uploaded) {
    $imagenNoticia - > image_resize = true;
    $imagenNoticia - > image_ratio = true;
    $imagenNoticia - > image_x = 573; //ancho
    $imagenNoticia - > image_ratio_y = true; //alto de acuerdo al ancho, mantiene perspectiva.
    $imagenNoticia - > image_watermark = '../img/watermark.png';
    $imagenNoticia - > image_watermark_position = 'TL';

    $imagenNoticia - > process('../img/noticias/');
    if ($imagenNoticia - > processed) {

      $statement = $conexion - > prepare("UPDATE noticias SET tituloNoticia = :tituloNoticia, noticiaCorta = :noticiaCorta, noticiaCompleta = :noticiaCompleta, imagenNoticia = :imagenNoticia WHERE idNoticia LIKE $idNoticia");

      $statement - > execute(array(
        ':tituloNoticia' => $tituloNoticia,
        ':noticiaCorta' => $noticiaCorta,
        ':noticiaCompleta' => $noticiaCompleta,
        ':imagenNoticia' => $imagenNoticia - > file_dst_name
      ));

      echo "La noticia ha sido editada correctamente.";
    }
}else{
      $statement = $conexion - > prepare("UPDATE noticias SET tituloNoticia = :tituloNoticia, noticiaCorta = :noticiaCorta, noticiaCompleta = :noticiaCompleta WHERE idNoticia LIKE $idNoticia");

      $statement - > execute(array(
        ':tituloNoticia' => $tituloNoticia,
        ':noticiaCorta' => $noticiaCorta,
        ':noticiaCompleta' => $noticiaCompleta
      ));

      echo "La noticia ha sido editada correctamente.";
}
```

Ademas revisaría, el where de la consulta "...WHERE idNoticioa LIKE $idNoticia", por hay dicen que es de programadores "si funciona no lo toques" pero si le pones el LIKE en lugar del =...

Comment: No funcionaria porque $imagenNoticia es un array y no funcionaria al reemplazarlo por $imagenNoticia_guardada, igualmente pregunté en el foro oficial de la clase class.upload.php y ya me dieron la solución por suerte. muchas gracias igualmente!